# Emails via rules are sent multiple times

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I created a rule to send an email to the author of the node after saving the node. In case of new nodes and whend changed existing ones.

But the mails are sent multiple times. Sometimes at the same time and sometimes over about 3 hours. Simetimes 10 emails, sometimes 20.

I don't know where I can search for a reason.

Comment: just add a another action to the rule to send u notification to see whether the notifications are triggered only by your rule.

Tf thats the case please share ur rule so that we can give u a credible answer.

Answer (score 1):

you might want to turn debugging on for your workflow (admin/config/workflow/rules/settings) and check the logs after the emails are sent (admin/reports/dblog)

I found out after hours of trying to solve a similar problem, that some triggers were being defined automatically in (admin/structure/trigger/workflow) for my workflow and they were saving and publishing my node again, thus creating a recursion. Drupal stops after a few iterations of this, so a random number of messages is being sent. My server was sending over 40 every time I changed workflow states

Also please look at your rules page and make sure you don't have any contradicting rules in your workflow that makes it run the same stuff all over again.